# Is it possible to declare a vector of pointers to floats with a specific size in cython?

Tags: pointers, vector, size, cython, declaration

Basically I had a vector defined as follows:

```
cdef vector[float*] x_sets
```

I have decided now I would like to do it with a specific size so that I can assign vectors of each set to a pointer in x_sets. When I try the following:

```
cdef vector[float*] x_sets = new vector[float*](num_sets)
```

I get an error `cannot assign type vector[float*] to vector[float*]`.

edit:
for more background, I'm basically trying to pass multiple datasets to some c++ code, and in the c++ code they are stored in a float** called xs_list for the x sets and ys_list for the y_sets.

Comment: This is because you're trying to assign a `vector[float*]*` (a pointer to a vector of float pointers) to a `vector[float*]`. Honestly this design seems like a bad in general idea, especially if you don't know C++ well enough to get a `vector*` can't be assigned to a `vector` value.

Comment: Fair point. I had honestly forgotten that new returned a pointer (I work mostly in python these days, hence the struggle here). I'm not looking for a full solution, but would you have any advice on passing multiple data sets from python to a wrapped c++ module using cython?

Comment: If you can modify the C++ interface I'd suggest using all STL (maybe `vector[set[float]]`, or if that doesn't fit `vector[vector[float]]`). If you can't then I'd do all the memory allocation yourself as arrays. The trouble with `vector[float*]` is that the vector _doesn't_ deallocate the float arrays so can easily go out of scope losing the memory, or end up pointing to memory that no-longer exists. My opinion is that mixing STL and manually allocated arrays is the worst of both worlds

Comment: I can definitely modify the C++ interface, so I think I will give the ```vector[vector[float]]``` a shot. Funnily enough, that was what I was originally trying to do, and honestly, at this point, I can't remember why I stopped with that approach. Anyways thank you.